# JSoup Returning IndexOutOfBoundsException when fetching data from Document

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Im having a really difficult time resolving the error i'm getting! To cut a story short, I am trying to get a specific element from a table in HTML! Easy right? Well that's what I thought.. Essentially, if I copy the exact HTML page source from the browser and read it in from a file, I can find the element that I need.

However, when reading through the document through document.connect("URL"), I'm getting the error! I've been sat here for about 4 hours now, reading around trying to understand what's going on. I'm fairly confident with JSoup but this has stumped me! The code is below:

```
private String parseKcal( Element kCalElement ) throws IOException {

//Getting error on below line
    String calories = kCalElement.select(".tableWrapper").select("tr").select(".tableRow0").select("td").get(0).text();
    if (calories == null) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    return calories.toString();
}
```

The parameter kCalElement is the document im trying to get the element from!

**** The error ****

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at models.Product.parseKcal(Product.java:67)
```

**** The HTML which i'm trying to parse ****

```
    <div class="tableWrapper">
    <table class="nutritionTable">
    <thead>
    <tr class="tableTitleRow">
    <th scope="col">Typical Values</th><th scope="col">Per 100g&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">% based on RI for Average Adult</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="tableRow1">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader" rowspan="2">Energy</th><td class="tableRow1">140kJ</td><td class="tableRow1">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow0">
    <td class="nutritionLevel1">33kcal</td><td class="nutritionLevel1">2%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow1">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Fat</th><td class="nutritionLevel1">&lt;0.5g</td><td class="nutritionLevel1">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow0">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Saturates</th><td class="nutritionLevel1">&lt;0.1g</td><td class="nutritionLevel1">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow1">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Carbohydrate</th><td class="tableRow1">6.1g</td><td class="tableRow1">2%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow0">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Total Sugars</th><td class="nutritionLevel2">6.1g</td><td class="nutritionLevel2">7%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow1">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Fibre</th><td class="tableRow1">1.0g</td><td class="tableRow1">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow0">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Protein</th><td class="tableRow0">0.6g</td><td class="tableRow0">1%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow1">
    <th scope="row" class="rowHeader">Salt</th><td class="nutritionLevel1">&lt;0.01g</td><td class="nutritionLevel1">-</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <p>RI= Reference Intakes of an average adult (8400kJ / 2000kcal)</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This does not work however when I paste the html into a string, it works!
See below:

```
 File input = new File("~/Desktop/file.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");



    Document document = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString());

    String calories = document.select(".tableWrapper").select("tr").select(".tableRow0").select("td").get(0).text();

    System.out.println(calories);
```

Can please someone help me from pulling my hair out! I am STUMPED :(

EDIT

---

I am trying to get the kcal element that contains calories!!!

Comment: Did you try printing out the different values or your select chain? Some logging might help you understand why there is no match to your selects!

Comment: Yes, Ive tried each one. I get something back everytime unless I use .get(0). I then get the error: IndexOutOfBounds ******

String calories = kCalElement.select(".tableWrapper").select("tr").select(".tableRow0").select("td").text(); returns "33kcal 2% <0.1g - 6.1g 7% 0.6g 1%"

I just need the calories so I use .get(0) and it throws exception

Comment: Because the returned value is not a list but a string. Either split it or use regex to extract the information you need !

Comment: For example `text.split(" ").get(0)`

Comment: Can you share a code snippet that shows your whole flow of fetching the URL and selecting? And which jsoup version are you using? My guess is that the server is giving you different content that what you saved when using a browser. But I can't verify from your example.

Comment: Also a simpler selector than your chain of selects would be `td.nutritionLevel1:eq(0)`, see for e.g.: http://try.jsoup.org/~598UT49QeBSk4xOl9fZAmjk6-uM